# difficulties in registering and login

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Here is the code:

```
include_once('class.database.php'); 

class ManageUsers{
    public $link;

    function __construct(){
        $db_connection = new dbConnection();
        $this->link = $db_connection->connect();
        return $this->link;
    }

    function registerUsers($password, $ip_address, $date, $time, $username, $email, $uname){
        $query = $this->link->prepare("INSERT INTO users (password,ip_address,date,time,username, email, uname) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        $values = array ($password, $ip_address, $date, $time, $username, $email, $uname);
        $query->execute($values);
        $count = $query->rowCount();
        return $count;
    }

    function LoginUsers($username, $password){
        $query = $this->link->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");
        $rowCount = $query->rowCount();
        return $rowCount;
    }
    function GetUserInfo($username){
        $query = $this->link->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
        $rowCount = $query->rowCount();
        if($rowCount ==1)
        {
            $result = $query->fetchAll();
            return $result;
        }
        else
        {
            return $rowCount;
        }
    }

}
```

and it is showing me this error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in
>   C:\wamp\www\timetable\class.ManageUsers.php on line 22

Comment: What does this have to do with JavaScript?

Comment: Which line is _line 22_?

Comment: Can you tag line 22 from your IDE please?

Comment: $query = $this->link->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");

Comment: Why does the constructor return `$link`?

Comment: could that be the problem pls? am just new and still learning this

Comment: you can't return values from a constructor. But anyway if $link is not an object, it appears that probably the operation to connect to the database failed. You aren't checking for errors though. Since you've obfuscated your underlying DB library within your dbConnection class, I can't tell you exactly what to do in order to expose connection errors, but you can look it up online.